# JS Как из n-мерного массива сделать двумерный?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста как из n-мерного массива сделать двумерный. Приведу пример

```js
let bigArr = [
  [
    [ 'Ячейка 1-1' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 1-2' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 1-3' ],
  ],
  [
    [ 'Ячейка 2-1' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 2-2' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 2-3' ],
  ],
  [
    [ 'Ячейка 3-1' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 3-2' ],
    [ 'Ячейка 3-3' ],
  ],
];


let bigArr2 = [
  [
[ 'Ячейка 1-1' ],
[ 'Ячейка 1-2' ],
[ 'Ячейка 1-3' ],
  ],
  [
[ 'Ячейка 2-1' ],

[ 'Ячейка 2-3' ],
  ],
  [
[ 'Ячейка 3-1' ],
[ 'Ячейка 3-2' ],
[ 'Ячейка 3-3' ],
  ],
];






let resultArr = [];
/*
[
  [ 'Ячейка 1-1', 'Ячейка 2-1', 'Ячейка 3-1'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-2', 'Ячейка 2-2', 'Ячейка 3-2'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-3', 'Ячейка 2-3', 'Ячейка 3-3'],
];
*/

/* For second variant for bigArr2
[
  [ 'Ячейка 1-1', 'Ячейка 2-1', 'Ячейка 3-1'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-2', 'empty', 'Ячейка 3-2'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-3', 'Ячейка 2-3', 'Ячейка 3-3'],
];
*/
```

Есть n-мерный массив, в котором 2-х уровней может быть очень много. Как его трансформировать в массив 2-го порядка ? `resultArr`

Comment: как определить, что именно такая строка `[ 'Ячейка 1-2', null, 'Ячейка 3-2'],` должна быть, а не `[ 'Ячейка 1-2', 'Ячейка 3-2', null],` либо `[ null, 'Ячейка 1-2', 'Ячейка 3-2'],`?

Comment: по сути наверное тут всё таки проверка на `undefined` а не `null` Согласен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для удаления вложенности можно воспользоваться методом [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

Для получения ожидаемого результата, итоговую матрицу можно просто транспонировать, а именно поменять местами элементы A<sub>(i,j)</sub> и A<sub>(j,i)</sub>

Сделать это можно с помощью метода [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let bigArr = [
  [
    ['Ячейка 1-1'],
    ['Ячейка 1-2'],
    ['Ячейка 1-3'],
  ],
  [
    ['Ячейка 2-1'],
    ['Ячейка 2-2'],
    ['Ячейка 2-3'],
  ],
  [
    ['Ячейка 3-1'],
    ['Ячейка 3-2'],
    ['Ячейка 3-3'],
  ],
];


let resultArr = bigArr.map(a => a.flat()).map((r, i, a) => r.map((c, j) => a[j][i]));

console.log(resultArr);
/*
[
  [ 'Ячейка 1-1', 'Ячейка 2-1', 'Ячейка 3-1'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-2', 'Ячейка 2-2', 'Ячейка 3-2'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-3', 'Ячейка 2-3', 'Ячейка 3-3'],
];
*/
```

В случае не квадратной матрицы, транспонирование стоит вынести в отдельную функцию

```js
let bigArr = [
  [
    ['Ячейка 1-1'],
    ['Ячейка 1-2'],
    ['Ячейка 1-3'],
  ],
  [
    ['Ячейка 2-1'],
    ['Ячейка 2-2'],
    ['Ячейка 2-3'],
  ]
];

function transponse(m) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
      if (!result[j]) result[j] = [];
      result[j][i] = m[i][j];
    }
  }
  return result;
}


let resultArr = bigArr.map(a => a.flat());
console.log(transponse(resultArr));
/*
[
  [ 'Ячейка 1-1', 'Ячейка 2-1'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-2', 'Ячейка 2-2'],
  [ 'Ячейка 1-3', 'Ячейка 2-3'],
];
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение. Можно ещё вопрос, а как быть если один из массивов второго уровня, не совпадает по количеству данных ? *Просто в реальном примере данные массивы (второго уровня) являются - промисами и если где-то они не полные `let bigArr2` то Ваш вариант не сработает правильно. Есть ли способ делать проверку... ну и там null ставить где надо в отсутствие данных? Вылетает с  ` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @BlackStar1991, у тебя нет результата для второго входного массива, поэтому непонятно что в итоге должно получиться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не очень понял, почему не понятно что должно получиться.... Должен выйти объект из совмещенных промисов нужного вида для дальнейшей работы с ним. По факту `bigArr` получил  `bigArr = await Promise.all([arr1, arr2, arr3])` но вот как с ним дальше работать, превратив в нужный вид, не пойму... пробую переназначать результат в другие переменные, всё равно не работает

Comment: @BlackStar1991, `Promise` тут нигде не появляется - так как после `await` у тебя будет массив значений. В комментарии выше речь шла про дырку, которая образуется в месте где отсутствует элемент. В вопросе ты привел пример, в котором в одном из массивов меньше элементов, но не привел ожидаемого результата для этого примера.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, добавь недостающую информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @BlackStar1991, тот пример который ты добавил в ответ невозможно реализовать, так как в общем случае невозможно узнать где именно нужно ставить `null`, пропущен ли у тебя какой-то элемент либо какого-то недостает в конце либо в начале.

Comment: Понял, был не прав, поправил

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132322/discussion-between-grundy-and-blackstar1991).